# BigQuery - Compare source and target table and insert new records only

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am writing a stored procedure to update target table from a source table.
The data comes in daily and will have data for the last 7 days as well.
I would like to only insert new data in to target table after comparing the source and target tables based on the Date column.

Not sure how to write this in BQ

```
if source.date = target.date
then dont insert
else 
insert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is (pseudo code) :

```
insert into target 
select * from source
where source.date <> target.date
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you assume that you have data from a given date or no data  If that is the case, the logic you want is:

```
insert into target ( . . . )   -- list the columns
    select . . .      -- list the columns
    from source s
    where not exists (select 1 from target t where t.date = s.date);
```

Comment: That will work,  but I am struggling to incorporate 2 conditions